# How to calculate the top offset of hidden elements?

Tags: jquery

I have elements hidden and i want calculate the top offset it how this is done?
i try this code but given offset top (0).
Note that the element I want to calculate the top offset has is hidden with a code CSS..{display:none}

```
console.log($('.section').offset().top);
```

This my code HTML

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class='section hide'>
    // my elements ..
    </div>
```

and this my code Css

```
.hide{dipslay:none}
```

Comment: Try
 .hide {
  visibility: hidden; 
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

Comment: thanks you for idea bro :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From jQuery API: https://api.jquery.com/offset/

> **Note:** jQuery does not support getting the offset coordinates of hidden elements or
>   accounting for margins set on the `<html>` document element.
>
> While it is possible to get the coordinates of elements with `visibility:hidden` set,
>   `display:none` is excluded from the rendering tree and thus has a position that is undefined.

You could use `visibility:hidden` but the element will take up space on the page. You could load the element as `visibility:hidden`, get the `.offset()`, save it to a variable, and then add the `.hide`.